# UIvew in different positions with the same code

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a test project with tab bars and I put another view programmatically above the tab bar, however it works with all of the view controllers except one.

[image: Not working]

[image: working]

my code is the same for setting the position:

```
topTapbarPosition = (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.minY)!

banner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topTapbarPosition - 50, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50).integral
```

I have tried a few different things, and nothing is working.

Comment: Consider using autolayout, unless you are prepared to handle each and every case where the layout of the hosting view changes.

Comment: I consider that at first, and it actually works correctly for everything except iPhones 11/12 pro and iPad Air. Every other screen size works.